# Поиск файлов Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Функция поиска файлов:

```
Procedure ScanDir(StartDir: String; Mask:string; List:TStrings);
Var SearchRec : TSearchRec;
Begin
  IF Mask ='' then Mask:= '*.*';
  IF StartDir[Length(StartDir)] <> '\' then StartDir := StartDir + '\';
  IF FindFirst(StartDir+Mask, faAnyFile, SearchRec) = 0 then
    Begin
     Repeat
        { Чтобы выполнение "не подвисало" }
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      IF (SearchRec.Attr and faDirectory) <> faDirectory then
         List.Add(StartDir + SearchRec.Name) else
          IF (SearchRec.Name <> '..') and (SearchRec.Name <> '.') then
        Begin
            { Рекурсивный вызов }
          ScanDir(StartDir + SearchRec.Name + '\',Mask,List);
        End;
     Until FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0;
     FindClose(SearchRec);
   End; {IF}
end;
```

**Как правильно реализовать:** Поиск нескольких форматов к примеру **.txt и .html**?

**Пыталась сделать вот так:**

```
Procedure ScanDir(StartDir: String; Mask:string; List:TStrings);
const
      N = 4;
      ArrExt : array[1..N] of String = (
        '.txt',
        '.html'
      );

    ............
if form1.CheckBox1.Checked then // если чекбок1 значит ищем .txt файл
     if StrExt = ArrExt[0] then begin
    ScanDir(StartDir + SearchRec.Name);

if form1.CheckBox2.Checked then // если чекбок2 значит ищем .html файл
     if StrExt = ArrExt[1] then begin
    ScanDir(StartDir + SearchRec.Name);
```

И на этом и остановилась.

Comment: Что за переменная `StrExt`, откуда она и что обозначает? Почему код вызова `ScanDir` не совпадает с показанной функцией? Сделайте нормальный пример плиз. Пока - минус.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И опять `Application.ProcessMessages`, отсутствие `finallly`

```
Procedure ScanDir(StartDir: String; List:TStrings);
Var
  SearchRec : TSearchRec;
  Res: Integer;
  Ext: string;
Begin
  Res := FindFirst(StartDir+*.*, faAnyFile, SearchRec);
  try
    while Res = 0 do begin
      { Чтобы выполнение "не подвисало" нужно вынести его в отдельный поток }
      // Application.ProcessMessages;
      IF (SearchRec.Attr and faDirectory) <> faDirectory then begin
        Ext := ExtractFileExt(SearchRec.Name);
        if
          (CheckBox1.Checked and SameText(Ext, '.txt') or
          (CheckBox2.Checked and SameText(Ext, '.html') or
          ............
        then
          List.Add(StartDir + SearchRec.Name);
      end else begin
        IF (SearchRec.Name <> '..') and (SearchRec.Name <> '.') then
        Begin
          { Рекурсивный вызов }
          ScanDir(StartDir + SearchRec.Name + '\',Mask,List);
        End;
      end;
      Res := FindNext(SearchRec);
    end;
  finally
    FindClose(SearchRec);
  end;
end;
```

Или в стиле последних Delphi

```
uses
  System.IOUtils;
.........
var
  files: array of string;
begin
  files := TDirectory.GetFiles(
    StartDir,
    '*.*',
    soAllDirectories,
    function(const Path: string; const SearchRec: TSearchRec): Boolean
      var ext: string;
    begin
      Ext := ExtractFileExt(SearchRec.Name);
      Result := 
        ((SearchRec.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory) or
        (CheckBox1.Checked and SameText(Ext, '.txt') or
        (CheckBox2.Checked and SameText(Ext, '.html') or
        ............
    end
  )
```

Comment: Обновила код в теме - посмотрите что не так. Не отображаются пути к файлам.

Comment: @Татьяна Вас, вроде уже просили модераторы кардинально не менять текст вопроса? Если появились вопросы по ответу = попросите уточнить в комментарии. Если появились новые вопросы - задайте их новыми

Comment: Все, разобралась. Оказывается - была проблема у меня, в путях, то есть добавила '\'. Теперь все работает, благодаря вашей помощи.